# Crypto perpetual futures (swaps) pricing away from instantaneous moment of funding

Tags: futures, pricing, forward, cryptocurrency

Most perpetual futures offered by crypto exchanges employ a funding payment mechanism, that acts to periodically return the price of the perpetual to the underlying index price. The mechanism is broadly outlined [here](https://www.binance.com/en/blog/futures/what-is-futures-funding-rate-and-why-it-matters-421499824684903247).

How does the funding mechanism ensure the perpetual price returns to the price of the underlying at the time funding is paid/received?  My understanding is that this should hold through arbitrage: in a positive funding rate environment a long underlying, short perpetual trade done the instance before funding payment, should not yield any profit - the funding payment is received (on the short perp) and the perp price moves by the funding amount (like the effect of stock price going ex-dividend).  This jump in perp price momentarily sets it back to the spot price.  Positive pnl on the funding received, negative pnl on the perp price move.  For the two pnls to offset, the perp price must move to the spot price.

So, there is a hard, closed-form relationship between spot price, perp price and funding payment **at the instance of funding**.

My question is, away from moment of funding is the any hard relationship that ties the perp price to spot, maybe via the expected funding rate?  Or can the perp price just float to wherever demand takes it and it's only bounded at the funding time.  Given the perpetual *feels* like a short-dated forward, I kinda expected something like [covered interest rate parity](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/forex/08/interes-rate-parity.asp) to dictate pricing, but I'm not sure that's correct.

Comment: I don’t see how you conclude that the perp and spot converge at the instant of funding.  It seems that you could only conclude that the perp jumps by the funding amount.

Comment: In my experience the funding payment does not impact the price of the perpetual directly. When this happens all trader that are positioned against the price deviation receive the payment directly to their accounts.

Say for example the perpetual trades above spot and you are long. Then you constantly pay the funding rate which should nudge you to reduce your position.

If the funding rate is big enough it will incentivize traders to take the opposite position. This can be done on an outright basis or as a spread to some futures contract.